# What is the difference between Shiva Temple Pradhikshina and just Shiva lingam pradhikshina?

Tags: shiva, temple, shiva-lingam

I have been going to Shivalayam (Shiva temple) and noticed that all People who circumambulate Shiva temple go a full circle, where as people circumambulating just the Shiva ling which is open for all to perform abhishekam just do a half a circle or so. I see people doing a full circle, but many just go half. Can someone please enlighten?

Comment: I think you are talking about the Somasukta Pradhakshinam when you said about people doing half circle. Refer this answer: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/603/81

Comment: @Dharmaputhiran Thank you for sharing your thoughts and link. I have gone through the link and this type of Pradhikshina is done with respect to the new moon (13th day), but here I notice devotees doing this everyday. And the do exactly as represented in the image of the above link. So, is it good to follow this type of Pradhikshinas everyday?

Comment: @sairam01: The reason might be "We should not cross or should not touch our feet to abishekam water while doing pradhikshina".

Comment: @Mahesh.D your reason applies equally to other gods as well. So the question that why is it followed only for Lord Shiva raises. Could you throw some light on it?

Comment: @Dharmaputhiran: 1) On head of lord Shiva Ganga will be there 2) Abishekam water flows left to Shiva Ligam (right for us when facing to Shiva Ligam). For other Gods scenario is differs.